Date script failing when imported from another page
I am using a date script on my website as part of my footer composition.
The code should produce the following (example):
© 2004 MYWEBSITE.COM All Rights Reserved
The script works fine in composition if I code it fully in each page.
However, when I created a 'footer.php' page, so I can insert the footer composition easier in each of my webpages, the date script part of the code fails.
The failed code produces the following (missing date):
© MYWEBSITE.COM All Rights Reserved
COMPOSITION (footer.php):
<div id="siteFooter">

<div class="copyright">&copy;&nbsp;<script>document.write(new 
Date().getFullYear())</script> MYWEBSITE.COM All&nbspRights&nbspReserved</div>

</div>

CSS:
#loadedFooter {display: flex;} 

.copyright {

font-family: arial;
font-size: 12pt;
color: grey;

}

INSERT CODE (in body of other pages):
<div id="loadedFooter"></div><script>$('#loadedFooter').load('footer.php #siteFooter'); 
</script>

INSERT SCRIPT (in head tag of other pages):
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/footer.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


read the jquery documentation for .load() - specifically the "script execution" description

Most people that use PHP would include the footer on the server side - like this SO question

@JaromandaX Thank you. I did read the document. I can't say that I entirely understand it enough to extract a solution. I will say though that I use an almost identical set of scripts and codes for the header and it does not fail.

the solution is to NOT use the .load( "article.html #target" ) form of load ... i.e. only the .load( "article.html" ); will execute scripts - why are you trying to only load the #siteFooter fragment of footer.php anyway, when that's the whole thing! also, I would NOT be using document.write in 2024 (or even 2014, but that's 10 years ago)

All of my pages are php, so the solution was to simply include the php include tags where I needed the footer file to go. 
